# Create/Change/Use an extern Variable in C

Tags: c, memory

I have a header file containing:

```
extern char *finalLoggerPath;
```

I am trying to implement a function that can initialize or modify the `finalLoggerPath` variable.

My `main` function indirectly calls a function defined in a second file.  This second function generates a path which does not yet exist, and saves it in two file-scope variables, `finalPath` and `finalLoggerPath`.  After that is done, I would like another function defined in a third file to be able to print the `finalLoggerPath`.

I have attempted to implement this, but I get an error:

> Memory access error (memory dump used)

How can I fix my program?

---

My code:

```
// First File

void initLog() {
    generateFileNameWithDate();
}

int main(void) {
    initLog();
}
```

---

```
// Second File

#define PATHTEST "../TestLogSystem/"

#include "Info.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char pathToFile[100] = "../TestLogSystem/";
char *actual;
char *finalPath;

char *finalLoggerPath;

int generateFileNameWithDate() {
    int counter = 1;
    char filename[999];
    char filenameBuffer[999];
    int notCreatetFile = 1;

    char counterS[999];
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    if (now == -1) {
        puts("The time() function failed");
        return 1;
    }

    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&now);

    if (ptm == NULL) {
        puts("The localtime() function failed");
        return 1;
    }

    strftime(filename, sizeof(filename),
            strcat(strcat(pathToFile, "%Y%m%d"), ".json"), ptm);

    while (notCreatetFile) {

        if (access(filename, F_OK) != -1) {
            // file exists
            memset(filename, 0, sizeof(filename));
            memset(pathToFile, 0, sizeof(pathToFile));

            sprintf(pathToFile, "%s", PATHTEST);

            memset(filenameBuffer, 0, sizeof(filenameBuffer));

            sprintf(counterS, "%d", counter);

            strftime(filename, sizeof(filename),
                    strcat(
                            strcat(
                                    strcat(
                                            strcat(strcat(pathToFile, filenameBuffer),
                                                    "%Y%m%d"), "-Test-"),
                                    counterS), ".json"), ptm);

        } else {
            // file doesn't exist
            finalPath = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);
            printf("finalPath: %s \n", finalPath);

            strcpy(finalPath, filename);
            strcpy(finalLoggerPath, finalPath);

            fopen(finalPath, "w");

            notCreatetFile = 0;
        }
        ++counter;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// Third File


#include "Info.h"

void print() {
    printf("FinalLoggerPath: %s", finalLoggerPath);
}
```

I compile it:

```
gcc CallFileExists.c FileExists.c GetVariableFromFileExists.c
```

Comment: How are you compiling and linking these files?  Also, it's bad practice to `#include` a .c file.

Comment: You are not allocating memory to `finalLoggerPath` anywhere and accessing it             `strcpy(finalLoggerPath, finalPath);`

Comment: C does not have classes, and in related languages that do, such as C++ and Java, a class is a very different thing from a function.  Please, then, do not confuse people by calling things "Class/Function" or "Function/Class".  Additionally, please cut back on use of that Shift key.  It makes your prose hard to read.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i edited my post and delete Class

Comment: @dbush I edited the code and remove the including in the code and compiling it with gcc CallFileExists.c FileExists.c GetVariableFromFileExists.c and then i use ./a.out for the output

Comment: @kiranBiradar How i allocating memory to finalLoggerPath, actualy where should i do that? in the generateFileNameWithDate Method?

Comment: My fault..... I thank you at all and actually @kiran the problem is solved..